# write in the middle of the page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, paging

I use the following codes for writing the page numbers at the middle of bottom of the page. but these codes will show page numbers in right of bottom of the page not in the middle.

```
    <?php
if($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages > 1){
echo '<div>';
get_paged_navigation();
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Also if it's possible please tell me how I can write that at the top of the footer because it shows bottom of the footer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP doesn't decide where the content is displayed on the page (not in the way you describe at least). This is a HTML/CSS question. That being said, we'll need to see some HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set width for div and put it to center of page with 'margin:auto'

```
echo '<div style="width:500px;margin:auto;">';
get_paged_navigation();
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: To make your answer better please include how and why this code will solve the OP's problem.